# Datetime in PowerShell can't convert my Time

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a Script to compare two sets of timevalues and then calculate a exact time.

My problem is the calculation with timestamps. I import the times from a .csv-file. The times look like this:

```
08:37;
11:47;
12:11;
17:34;
etc.
```

I made a variable for the times so i always have the correct time from the correct line from the csv file.
My goal ist to calculate the time from one timestamp to another like this:  11:47 - 08:37 = 3:10

If i do this in my PowerShell Script an error occurs: The value "time=12:39" can not be converted to type "System.DateTime". Error: "The string was not recognized as a DateTime. An unknown word starts at index 1"

Is datetime wrong in this case? How can i make this work?

Thx for your help.

Comment: Please show us more of the input CSV you're using. Does it have headers? Are there **two** fields as it appears now? (one with the time and the second being empty)?

Comment: The csv looks like this:
name;prename;date;time;
Gantz;Mario;09.02.;07:37
Gantz;Mario;09.02.;11:23
Gantz;Mario;09.02.;12:34
Gantz;Mario;09.02.;17:03

If i put the time into a variable and try to calculate with it i get the error like i sait in my post.

Comment: Now that I can see there is also a `date` column in the csv, please see my edit to include that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this has to do with your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66207262/9898643) and the CSV actually looks like this:

```
name;prename;date;time
Gantz;Mario;09.02.;07:37
Gantz;Mario;09.02.;11:23
Gantz;Mario;09.02.;12:34
Gantz;Mario;09.02.;17:03
```

Then this should do it

```
# create two variables to hold the times parsed from the CSV, Initialize to $null
$current, $previous = $null
# load the csv and loop through the records
$result = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\times.csv' -Delimiter ';' | ForEach-Object {
    $current = [datetime]::ParseExact($_.time, 'HH:mm', $null)
    if (!$previous) { $previous = $current }
    # subtracting two DateTime objects results in a TimeStamp
    $elapsed  = $current - $previous
    $previous = $current
    # output the record with column 'elapsed' appended
    $_ | Select-Object *, @{Name = 'elapsed'; Expression = {$elapsed.ToString()}}
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to new CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\times_and_intervals.csv' -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output on screen:

```
name  prename date   time  elapsed 
----  ------- ----   ----  ------- 
Gantz Mario   09.02. 07:37 00:00:00
Gantz Mario   09.02. 11:23 03:46:00
Gantz Mario   09.02. 12:34 01:11:00
Gantz Mario   09.02. 17:03 04:29:00
```

---

Now that I see you also have a 'date' column in there, you should include that in the conversion to [datetime] aswell:

```
# create two variables to hold the times parsed from the CSV, Initialize to $null
$current, $previous = $null
# load the csv and loop through the records
$result = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\times.csv' -Delimiter ';' | ForEach-Object {
    $completeDate = '{0}{1} {2}' -f $_.date, (Get-Date).Year, $_.time
    $current = [datetime]::ParseExact($completeDate, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm', $null)
    if (!$previous) { $previous = $current }
    # subtracting two DateTime objects results in a TimeStamp
    $elapsed  = $current - $previous
    $previous = $current
    # output the record with column 'elapsed' appended
    $_ | Select-Object *, @{Name = 'elapsed'; Expression = {$elapsed.ToString()}}
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to new CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\times_and_intervals.csv' -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are not specifying the values that you are importing as `[datetime]`
I have replicated the error where I just specified 2 time values and subtracted them:

> $st = "08:37" $et = "11:47" $di = $st - $et Cannot convert value
> "08:37" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a
> correct format."
> [image]

**Solution:**
Specify the values of each entry like so:

```
[datetime]$starttime = "08:37"
[datetime]$endtime = "11:47"
$diff = $endtime - $starttime
```

[image]

If you just want the time in minutes etc. you can enter `$diff.Minutes` respectively

Hope this works for you.